# Increment value of every element in an array in a particular range

Tags: arrays, loops, logic, time-complexity, increment

There's an array A[] having n elements. There's another array B[] of the same size n with every element initialized to zero. For every i in range 1 to n, elements of B[] in the range i-A_i to i+A_i (inclusive) need to be increased by 1.

I've already tried an O(n^2) solution using nested loop method. I cannot really figure out an O(n) solution if existent.

```
i=1;
while(i<=n)
{
start=(i-A[i]<1)?1:i-A[i];
end=(i+A[i]>n)?n:i+A[i];
while(start<=end)
{
B[start]+=1;
start+=1;
}
i+=1;
}
```

Comment: You should not increment the range itself each time, but keep track of how much to iterate, and then thus later do that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Could you please be a bit more elaborate about your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive implementation is to to increment each range per item in *A*, but you do not need to do taht. You can first "prepare" your array by adding `1` where the increment should start, and `-1` where the increment should stop. Next you can calculate the *cummulative* sum of the array. Like:

```
def fill_list(la):
    lb = [0]*len(la)
    n1 = len(la)-1
    for i, a in enumerate(la, 1):
        xf, xt = i-a, i+a+1
        lb[max(0, i-a)] += 1
        if xt <= n1:
            lb[xt] -= 1
    c = 0
    for i, b in enumerate(lb):
        c += b
        lb[i] = c
    return lb
```

or if you want to return the range from 1 to n:

```
def fill_list1(la):
    n1 = len(la)
    lb = [0]*(n1+1)
    for i, a in enumerate(la, 1):
        xf, xt = i-a, i+a+1
        lb[max(0, i-a)] += 1
        if xt <= n1:
            lb[xt] -= 1
    c = 0
    for i, b in enumerate(lb):
        c += b
        lb[i] = c
    return lb[1:]
```

We can then for example generate a list with:

```
>>> fill_list([1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2])
[4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3]
>>> fill_list1([1,2,3,4,5])
[5, 5, 4, 4, 3]
```

This thus has ranges for:

```
 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--
           |-----|
     |-----------------------|
              |-----------|
        |-----------------------------|
                       |-----|
                    |-----------------|
                                |
                             |-----------|
--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--
  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -2 -1
--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--
  0  1  2  3  4  4  4  5  5  5  4  3  3  1  0
```

The increments that are done before the start of the range (so with an index less than 0) are just placed at index `0` such that we take these into account. The ones that are  done after the window (so with an index larger than or equal to *n* are simply ignored).

In the image the first row shows the indices, next we denote the ranges that arise from the same input, next we show the increments and decrements that would be put on an infinite tape, and next we show the cummulative sum.

The algorithm works in *O(n)*: first we iterate over `la` in linear time, and increment and decrement the corresponding elements in `b`. Next we iterate over `b`, again in *O(n)* to calcuate the cummulative sum.

Comment: If I consider the array A=[1,2,3,4,5], array B should be B=[3,4,4,5,5] according to the conditions specified my question. The code you suggested shows an output of B=[4,4,5,5,5]. :(

Comment: @YashSarwaswa: why should the array be `[3,4,4,5,5]`? All ranges start at `0` here, so the ranges are `(0,2), (0, 4), (0, 6)`...

Comment: @YashSarwaswa: the output suggested is thus `[5, 5, 4, 4, 3]`, since at index `0`, it is 5, at index `1` again `5`, etc.